# Django json loads fails because of empty query dict in request Object

Tags: ajax, django, local-storage

I have ajax call posted to /cart/total where I am dumping JSON string stored in local storage using post when I run json loads it shows me the error.

```
TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not QueryDict
```

and my JSON string before parsing looks like having an empty feild, which I am not aware of in Django

```
<QueryDict: {'{"32":1,"33":1,"34":2}': ['']}>
```

```
<script>


    function addtocart(mitem, mprice) {

        if(localStorage.getItem('cart')==null){
            // var mobj = {}
            // var countQ ={}
            var price = String(mprice)
            var mobj = { [String(mitem)]: 1 }
            var countQ = {'Quantity':1}
            var storeobj = JSON.stringify(mobj)
            var storeCountq = JSON.stringify(countQ)
            localStorage.setItem('cart', storeobj)
            localStorage.setItem('quantity',storeCountq)
            console.log(localStorage.getItem('cart'))
        }else{
            var data = localStorage.getItem('cart')
            var quant = localStorage.getItem('quantity')
            var obj = JSON.parse(data)
            var parsequant = JSON.parse(quant)
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(String(mitem))){
                obj['%s',mitem]++
                parsequant['Quantity']++
                var storeobj = JSON.stringify(obj)
                console.log(localStorage.getItem('cart'))
                var storeCountq = JSON.stringify(parsequant)
                localStorage.setItem('cart', storeobj)
                localStorage.setItem('quantity', storeCountq)
            }
            else{
                obj[String(mitem)] = 1
                parsequant['Quantity']++
                var storeobj = JSON.stringify(obj)
                console.log(localStorage.getItem('cart'))
                var storeCountq = JSON.stringify(parsequant)
                localStorage.setItem('cart', storeobj)
                localStorage.setItem('quantity', storeCountq)
            }
        }
        }

    function ajaxcall(){
            $.ajax(
                        {
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/cart/total",
                            data: localStorage.getItem('cart'),
                            success: function () {
                                console.log("sent tdata")
                            }
                        })
                }

        ajaxcall()
    </script>
```

```
 <p style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px"><button class="button" style="width: 200px" onclick="addtocart( '{{M.Menu_Item_Id}}', '{{M.Menu_ItemPrice}}' )" >Add to cart</button>
```

view function

```
@csrf_exempt
def cartpricecalculator(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.POST)
        print(request.POST)

    return HttpResponse('200 Okay')
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, any help is appreciated.

Comment: The only I found to pass without breakage is json object straight and then convert query dict to dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.POST` is for form data. You need;

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
```

Comment: This was Brilliant idea @Daniel, never knew you could just get body

Answer (score 0):

Try:

In JS, pass a dict instead of a string. As per the documentation of ajax, data must be an Object with key and value or stringify of an Object with key and value.

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
function ajaxcall(){
            $.ajax(
                        {
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/cart/total",
                            data: {'cart': localStorage.getItem('cart')},
                            success: function () {
                                console.log("sent tdata")
                            }
                        })
                }
```

In python

```
@csrf_exempt
def cartpricecalculator(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cart_data = json.loads(request.POST.get('cart', '{}'))
        print(request.POST)
        print(request.POST.get('cart'))

    return HttpResponse('200 Okay')
```

Comment: Nice, this method works. Now I know how to do it according to the API standards. Thank you @sun_jara.

Comment: Glad that I could help.

Comment: If you don't mind, please accept the solution. Thanks @HarshNagarkar